# I can't change permissions

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

So my "code ." command doesn't work. I get the error

```
/usr/local/bin/code2: line 6: python: command not found
/usr/local/bin/code2: line 10: ./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory
```

I saw that I just have to change `python` to `python3` in the `code` file in `/usr/local/bin`. Except when I change the file, I'm unable to save it with the change. I get all sorts of errors telling me I don't have permission to change it. So then I look up how to change it, and it says to click on `get info` on the file, and then change the permissions in the sharing and permissions section. But my `get info` doesn't HAVE a sharing and permissions section!

What do I do?

PS: I realized I can see permissions if I do `get info` on the whole `bin` directory. I made it so everyone can read & write. Except I still can't save the altered version of the `code` file. I still don't know what to do anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I still have no idea how to save an edited version of the `code` file, but here is how I got around it for now.

```
brew install python
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Now I can use `code .` but I'm still very upset with my computer for not cooperating with me.

Comment: your OS might need to use python2, do you now have eliminated it

Comment: @rioV8 How do I fix this? And do you know how I can just change python to python3 in the code file and save it?

Comment: you have to change the Python interpreter in VSC, read the Python VSC doc page, if you need to change the `#!` line find the full path of the python3 interpreter